# How to concatenate cell (row wise) in excel till a value is found?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in MS excel sheet as :

```
Row     Column A
1   AAA Number of ABC
2   Streaming Call
3   Explanation
4   BBB Number of ABC
5   Streaming Call
6   from source
7   Explanation
8   CCC Number of ABC
9   Streaming Call
10  from source
11  to Dest
12  Explanation
...
...
196000  Explanation
```

I want to keep concatenating cell of column A in column B, till the cell value is "Explanation" :

```
1   AAA Number of ABC   AAA Number of ABC
2   Streaming Call          AAA Number of ABC Streaming Call
3   Explanation         Explanation
4   BBB Number of ABC   BBB Number of ABC
5   Streaming Call          BBB Number of ABC Streaming Call
6   from source         BBB Number of ABC Streaming Call from source
7   Explanation         Explanation
8   CCC Number of ABC   CCC Number of ABC
9   Streaming Call          CCC Number of ABC Streaming Call
10  from source         CCC Number of ABC Streaming Call from source
11  to Dest                 CCC Number of ABC Streaming Call from source to Dest
12  Explanation         Explanation
...
....
```

Can somebody suggest me formula that I can paste in Column B and drag to get desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reluctant to just write code for you, but it's an easy one so why not... Put in B2:

```
=IF(ROW()=1,A2,IF(A2="Explanation","Explanation",CONCATENATE(IF(A1="Explanation","",B1),A2)))
```

Drag up and down.

Comment: Hi John, Appreciate you help..I had to paste this in B2 as my data is in column A, Also just added space in concatenate formula :=IF(ROW()=1,A2,IF(A2="Explanation","Explanation",CONCATENATE(IF(A1="Explanation","",B1)," ",A2)))..Thanks Alott

Comment: Yeah... meant B2. My bad.