# Concatenate until "text"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in one row and I want to concatenate but defining the range to the before next cell including word "template".

Example of what I am after.
[image: Data and Desired Results]

I had a look at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614441/how-to-concatenate-cell-row-wise-in-excel-till-a-value-is-found" but it is not working for me.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far and what problems you encountered.

Comment: I have tried the solution from Leo and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim cel As Range
Dim tail As String



For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells 'check each cell of the data column

If InStr(cel.Value, "template") <> 0 Then 'check if current cell contains the keyword "template"

  i = 1
  tail = ""

  'gather all the following cells that does not cotain the keyword as a string called "tail"
  Do While InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row + i, 1).Value, "template") = 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row + i, 1).Value <> ""
    tail = tail & ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row + i, 1).Value
      i = i + 1
  Loop

  ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row, 2).Value = cel.Value & tail 'final result

End If
Next cel


End Sub
```

It's a crude solution, but I think it'll work.

Comment: Hey Leo, Thank you for your quick response. It unfortunately did not fully work. This below is the results Ive obtained. Could you please look into it? Thank you. https://imgur.com/94gnf1E

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the code, please try the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Sub CustomConctat()
    Dim txt As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long, concatGroupStartRow As Long
    i = 1
    concatGroupStartRow = 1
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Do While i < lastRow
        txt = txt + Cells(i, 1)
        ' If next row has template keyword, then insert concatenated text into
        ' first row in that group, in B column.
        If InStr(Cells(i + 1, 1), "template") Then
            Cells(concatGroupStartRow, 2).Value = txt
            txt = ""
            concatGroupStartRow = i + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```